# How do I query a table in SQL to display data with same foreign key and join it with data from another table(parent table)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I have two tables in sql database; `course_table` and `department_table`, the data contained in the tables respectively are displayed in the pictures below.

[department table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHzWR.png)

[course table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KYFQ2.png)

I'm required to run a query that will get all the `courses` offered in the `course` table that has a particular **department code**, say `dept_1`, then join it with the department name from the department table and get is displayed

Here is what i have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM COURSE WHERE DEPT_CODE = 'CS';
```

[And in this picture contains the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo7pU.png)

Comment: Look up "How to do SQL join", it's a pretty basic part of SQL queries

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See [How to put tables in Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302471/how-to-put-tables-in-stack-overflow)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM course_table
JOIN department_table ON 
department_table.DEPT_CODE=course_table.DEPT_CODE
WHERE DEPT_CODE = 'CS';
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your response. however, i changed the last line to this;  `WHERE COURSE.DEPT_CODE = 'CS';` and it worked. therefore, the correct version of the code is this `SELECT * 
FROM COURSE
JOIN DEPARTMENT ON 
DEPARTMENT.DEPT_CODE=COURSE.DEPT_CODE
WHERE COURSE.DEPT_CODE = 'CS';` another issue is that every field that matched the criteria 'CS' was selected. is there a way to select only the department name and join it with the courses